# How to add and remove elements in array in Mongo use Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

So I have object:

```
"_id" : 1,
"employee_id" : [2, 3, 4, 5],
"project_name" : "qwerty"
```

And I want to delete from `"employee_id"` array `[3, 5]` and add new array `[13, 6, 8]`. And result will be:

```
"_id" : 1,
"employee_id" : [2, 4, 13, 6, 8],
"project_name" : "qwerty"
```

I use this Java-code:

```
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("employee_service");
DBCollection collectionProject = database.getCollection("project");

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", project.getId());

DBObject projectMongoObject = new BasicDBObject();
projectMongoObject.put("project_name", project.getProjectName());

//something
collectionProject.update(query, projectMongoObject);
```

So how to set in `projectMongoObject` new array and delete array?

Comment: Have you tried requesting the existing array and updating with the extended array through overwriting?

Comment: @Smutje, no. But if I understand correctly, I will twitch database for: select array, add to array, delete from array, update project name. Is this a good idea?

Comment: No, just request the DB for the existing array, extend the object and request the DB to update the object containing the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [$pullAll](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) operator to remove the fields, and the combination of [$push and $each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) to add new fields to the array.

```
   DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
   query.put("_id", project.getId());   
   DBObject projectMongoObject = new BasicDBObject();
   projectMongoObject.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("project_name",
                                                     project.getProjectName()));
   projectMongoObject.put("$pullAll", 
                          new BasicDBObject("employee_id", new int[]{3,5}));
   collectionProject.update(query, projectMongoObject);
   projectMongoObject = new BasicDBObject();
   projectMongoObject.put("$push", 
                            new BasicDBObject("employee_id",
                                              new BasicDBObject("$each",
                                                            new int[]{13,6,8})));
   collectionProject.update(query, projectMongoObject);
```

Comment: Can I add and delete element's from array use 1 request to database?

Comment: No you cannot do that. Currently its a limitation in MongoDB.

Comment: One Minute, you can two fields at a time, that is possible, at the same time you cannot do two different operations on an single field. See my updated answer. Have edited to show that you can add elements to an array at the same time set the `project_name` field as well.

Comment: I have some problem: my new `project_name` value doesn't saving in database when I use `"$set"`

Comment: Are you using the `$set` operator to set the value for the field? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I remake code. At the begin I check add array size, and if it doesn't equals 0, I add `"$set"` to update request. If add array size equals 0, I add `"$set"` to update request for delete array. If both array size equals 0, I create new update request. I haven't error, but I haven't new value in `project_name`